# Jquery Mobile Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, tablet

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
alert('scrolling');
});
```

That is the code that works ok on a desktop computer but does not fire when scrolled on a mobile device.

Does anyone know if JQuery can support this?

Comment: I just tested it on an Android device and it seems to work. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D7yKK/1/show/) and [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/D7yKK/1/)

Comment: Which mobile device are you using? OS? Browser?